# gcoud syntax for access config deletion

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to delete the access config on an Google cloud compute VM instance I've tried the following with no luck. Can someone tell me the correct syntax please?

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 --access-config-name external-nat --zone us-central1-b

gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 --access-config-name --zone us-central1-b

gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 --access-config-name natIP --zone us-central1-b
```

The error is

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.delete-access-config) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid access config name.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first syntax you had is correct. To see the names of the access configs that can be deleted, run:

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe <INSTANCE NAME> --zone=<ZONE> --format='value(networkInterfaces[].accessConfigs[].name.list())'
[u'external-nat']
```

Then, run:

```
$ gcloud compute instances delete-access-config <INSTANCE> --zone=<ZONE> --access-config-name=external-nat
Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/cloudsdktest/zones/<ZONE>/instances/<INSTANCE>].
```

If that doesn't work, there must be some other issue, but the syntax is correct. Post the output of:

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe <INSTANCE> --zone=<ZONE> --format='json(networkInterfaces)'
```

for help debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config instance-1 --access-config-name="External NAT" --zone us-central1-b
```